# functionality should apply to all pages but it's applying only in one place

Tags: c#

I have a couple of functionalities like Add column, Merge the columns, Split the columns and Find and Replace options in a form.

I have a requirement called where i need to read a file and display in datagridview. 
NOTE: A file contains 1000 lines but i have to show only 100 at the time of loading and if we want to view next records, we have click NEXT button (it loads the next 100 lines).
I'm done with this requirement and it's working fine.

Now the problem is If i use any functionality like Merge the 2 columns, it's merging 2 columns and giving result for only 100 lines in first page not for whole 1000 lines.

Can anyone resolve my issue?
Below is the code i'm pasting for merging 2 columns:

FORM1:

```
private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmMerge fs = new frmMerge(dataGridView1);
    fs.cmbColumn1.DataSource = cmbList;

    for (int i = 0; i <= cmbList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        fs.cmbColumn2.Items.Add(cmbList[i]);
    }
    fs.ShowDialog();
}

Browse button code (where i select the file and read it into datagridview):

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Desktop";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "dat files (*.DAT)|*.DAT|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FileName);
        datfile = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            //Added on 2015-12-02
            maxRec = datfile.Length - 1;
            PageCount = maxRec / pageSize;
            LoadPage(MyFOrmat);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for us to work with. Also, it's not very clear what you're after.

Comment: I have reposted the question. Can you please help me on this

Comment: Could you please read the [mcve] link and then post code that meets that requirement?